# int and float in function overloading

Tags: c++, floating-point, int, overloading

I have two overloaded function like below:

```
void print(int i) { ... }
void print(float f) { ... }
```

Its giving me this error for `print(1.2);`:

```
error: call of overloaded 'print(double)' is ambiguous
```

Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Which conversion do you want ? double -> int or double -> float ?

Comment: It just so happens that C++ specifies `double->int` to be equally valid to `double->float`. One of those could have been made better than the other, but that wasn't the decision made.

Comment: Try this: `print(1.2f);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.2 is a double literal not a float.

So the compiler requires an explicit disambiguation.

1.2f would work as that is a float literal.

Answer (score 1):

It is interpreting 1.2 as a double.  Casting it to a float will solve the problem.

print( float(1.2) );

Comment: Plus one, but strictly speaking suffixing an f is not a cast.

Answer (score 1):

`1.2` is a `double` literal, making the function you're trying to call ambiguous - a `double` can just as easily be truncated to a `float` or to an `int`. Using a `float` literal (`1.2f`) or explicitly casting it would solve the problem.